# Where can we find astronomical real world data (spectral radiance and wavelength particularly) of a star?

Tags: star, black-body

I have my college project and I thought of finding the temperature of a star with the black-body curve of star but i need real data.
I searched but can't find the thing what I want. all I am getting is ready-made graphs of it.

I need the datas in numbers and not just graphs.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to pick a particular astronomical instrument or science mission and go to their website. Almost all astronomy projects are required to release their data to the public and they almost always link to their data from the website for that mission/instrument.

For example, the Sloan Digital Sky Survey which produces spectra for a huge number of stars has access to their spectra [right here](https://dr14.sdss.org/optical/spectrum/view?run2d=v5_10_0&plateid=4055&mjd=55359&fiberid=596&action=search). You can download the fits files directly and start playing around with the actual data yourself.